# Error: No SLF4J providers were found, en una conexion JDBA

Tags: java, maven, connection

Estoy implementado jdba para un sistema de conexion con mysql y java, en donde a travez de una interfaz de java muy simple estaba creando, editando y eliminando registros en mi base de datos, todo esta estba bien mientras tenia una conection factory simple, pero para tener como un sistema de conexion mas amplio implmente mi conection factory como un pool y lo hice de esta manera:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    public ConnectionFactory() {
        var pooledDatSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        pooledDatSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tienda?useTimeZone=true&serverTimeZone=UTC");
        pooledDatSource.setUser("root");
        pooledDatSource.setPassword("123456");
        pooledDatSource.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        this.dataSource = pooledDatSource;
    }
    public Connection recuperaConexion() throws SQLException {
        return this.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Y mi clase principal es como sigue a continuacion:

```
public class ControlDeStockMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ControlDeStockFrame produtoCategoriaFrame = new ControlDeStockFrame();
        produtoCategoriaFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Y mi pom.xml tengo implementadas estas dependencias:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Pero cuando ejecuto mi programa me muestra la ventan grafica sobre la que ejecuto mis acciones de crear, borrar o cambiar mis registros, pero no guarda los cambios y ademasme esta arrojando este error, cabe resalar que estoy trabajando sobre maven en el editor de intellij idea, este es el error que me sale:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
MLog initialization issue: slf4j found no binding or threatened to use its (dangerously silent) NOPLogger. We consider the slf4j library not found.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mchange.v2.log.MLog).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Ya probe implmentar varias opciones como esta, pero no tengo solucion a mi problema:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j2-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te muestra es una advertencia, no un error, el cual te informa que no está funcionando el mecanismo de log. En el texto del error te refiere a una [página de SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders).

Dicha página dice que hay que agregar un provider al proyecto, y sugiere varios. Para esta ocasión voy a elegir *slf4j-simple.jar*, que permite crear mensajes sencillos en el log.

En tu pom.xml veo que estás importando dos veces la misma biblioteca con versiones distintas, *spring-data-commons*. Te sugiero borrar la siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Ahora tenemos que determinar qué versión de *slf4j-simple* hay que descargar. Viendo las bibliotecas que descarga Maven, se importa la versión 2.0.2 de *slf4j-api*, que será la versión a agregar.

Buscando en MVN Repository encontramos [la entrada para agregar al pom.xml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.2) y así agregar la biblioteca al proyecto.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Basta con hacer un build del proyecto para que se descarguen y agreguen al proyecto las dependencias.

Para probar podemos crear un log así:

```
final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class); // Main es un ejemplo de clase
```

y para crear un registro en el log

```
log.info("Mensaje");
```